# Not able to update table using findById method from crudRepository

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to update my entry using crudRepository in spring boot the controller code is:

```
@RequestMapping("/edit-booking")
public String updateBooking(@RequestParam int id,HttpServletRequest request) {
    request.setAttribute("bookings", bookingService.editBooking(id));
    request.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_UPDATE");
    return "Administrator";
}
```

In the service:

```
public Booking editBooking(int id) {
    return bookingRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);

}
```

I am getting this error-

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
here was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Comment: Which address are you using to call your service ? The problem seems more related to a HTTP request not matching your endpoint (e.g there may be a typo in `"/edit-bookig"`) .

Comment: And while you're fixing that typo, also change the name of the request attribute to "booking" instead of "bookings". There's only one booking, so the final s is confusing.

Comment: thanks but now it's not updating instead it is saving as new entry.

Comment: any error? please let us know

Comment: can you update api call contract ?